# Smart Contract execution in Casper

Tags: mining, evm, gpu

Once the Casper POS update releases, will miners still be using GPU to execute smart contracts and power the EVM?

My understanding is that this form of 'mining' will still exist, but it wont lead to the spontaneous generation of new ETH tokens - but will instead garnish gas as a reward. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even **now**, GPUs are *not used for the EVM*. Mining is simply deliberate busywork, a way to spend computational resources with an easy way to prove that it happened in retrospect. Smart contracts and the EVM are totally done by the CPUs of every full node.

**Post-Casper**, GPUs likely *won't be used at all.* Casper does not require heavy computation, let alone deliberately wasteful ones. In a pure PoS world, validators (the PoS equivalent of miners) run smart contracts and the EVM on their own CPUs. In addition to transaction fees, they *might* be paid a subsidy of new ETH. (As far as I know, this has not been finalized.)

However, the current plan (as of May 2017) is for a stage of a PoS/PoW hybrid chain, where both Casper and PoW miners will coexist

Comment: How will the hybrid work? Half blocks pow and half casper?

Comment: That might be better asked as a separate question. In short: PoW miners mine all the blocks, but validators attempt to finalize the chain every 100 blocks.